# Proper way to use MongoDB client in async/await Express routers

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

What is the proper way to manage MongoDB clients in async/await Express routers?

I'm trying to create a MongoDB client in a router middleware so that it's available to all requests. Here's a simplified example:

```
const express = require('express');
const { MongoClient } = require('mongodb');

let router = express.Router();

router.use(async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
        req.client = await MongoClient.connect(process.env.MONGODB_URI);
        next();
    } catch (err) {
        next(err);
    } finally {
        req.client && req.client.close();
    }
});

router.get('/', async (req, res, next) => {
    let user = await users.findOne({ name: 'foo' });
    if (!user) {
        user = { name: 'foo' };
        await users.insert(user);
    }
    res.json(user);
});

module.exports = router;
```

Unfortunately, after calling `await users.findOne({ name: 'foo' })`, the execution jumps to the `finally` branch in the middleware, the MongoDB connection is closed, and the potential call to `await users.insert(user)` fails because of that.

Thanks for help!

Comment: You shouldn't create a new MongoClient instance for each request; instead, create it once at the top of your application and pass it around (for instance through `app.locals`, which is accessible in routers/middleware as `req.app.locals`).

Comment: Thanks @robertklep, that sounds good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where are you getting your users collection from?

And after properly getting users collection you can promisify all your db calls.

You can use Promise.all to resolve all at once

```
const [user1, user2] = await Promise.all([users.findOne({name: 'user1'}), users.findOne({name: 'user2'})]);
```

This will resolve both the promise at once.

**Edit After Code update 1**

you can use `{upsert: true}`

```
const user = await users.findOneAndUpdate({name: 'foo'}, {name: 'foo'}, {upsert: true})
```

And since your next() is an async call your code will definitely move to finally block.

```
const express = require('express');
const { MongoClient } = require('mongodb');

let router = express.Router();

router.use(async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
        req.client = await MongoClient.connect(process.env.MONGODB_URI);
        next();
    } catch (err) {
        next(err);
    }
});

router.get('/', async (req, res, next) => {
    let user = await users.findOne({ name: 'foo' });
    if (!user) {
        user = { name: 'foo' };
        await users.insert(user);
    }
    res.json(user);

    next();
});

router.use(async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
        req.client && req.client.close();
    } catch (err) {
        next(err);
    }
})

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: Thank you @Neeraj, this would work nicely. However, with your answer I've realized that I've simplified the situation too much. I actually need to execute certain logic between the two database queries. Let me update the example code to reflect that.